# drag, resize jquery plugin that support touch and gestures

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, touch, uigesturerecognizer

i have been all around the internet for days now finding a plugin that allow

1. List item
2. dragging div's
3. resize div's
4. touch events.
5. Gestures Resize

I found many options yet every one has it flaws.

**Jquery Ui + jquery.ui.touch-punch**

Is currently best supporting both clicks and touches yet **DOES NOT SUPPORT GESTURES resize**

**Touch Box**

Very smooth touch, yet very buggy with clicks, Cannot handle div that has overflow (scroll) as it misunderstand swap to scroll as if its dragging. also lack Containment, and setting dragging handle.

So is there any fix for jquery ui to understand gestures ? or is there ready made plugin that support gestures, containment and handle ?

thanks community :)

Answer (score 1):

you may want to try jQuery Panzoom:
http://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/demo/